# Replicating a String in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a long list containing names of shipping lanes. Here's a snippet:

```
names <- c("NorthHampton to EastHartford", "NorthHampton to Edison", "NorthHampton to Yonkers", 
           "North Hampton to Brooklyn", "NorthHampton to Rotterdam" )
```

I want to create a new dataframe with a column that contains each item from my list replicated 3 times.

```
Col1    

Northampton to East Hartford
Northampton to East Hartford
Northampton to East Hartford
Northampton to Edison
Northampton to Edison
Northampton to Edison
Northampton to Yonkers
.
.
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this I've just been having trouble. I've been thinking something along the lines of

```
col1 <- as.data.frame( seq(rep(names,3)) )
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `as.data.frame( rep(names,3))`

Comment: Thanks, dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.frame(Col1=rep(names,each=3))
```